# Checking user's youtube quota before uploading the video

Tags: youtube-api

When using YouTube Data API, then do we need to check quota before uploading the video. What I am doing, after authentication and exchanging the token, I am saving access_token, refresh_token and expires_in.

Then with the help of access_token I am able to upload video. But just wanted to know do I need to check any quota usage beforehand.

[Uploads a video to YouTube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert?authuser=2)

One important thing: Logged in user (narendardiscover@gmail) will be uploading the video after giving access to MyApp2018. Please see the attached image. So video will be uploaded on narendardiscover youtube account. So do I need to check any quota of narendardiscovoer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Quota is tracked for a Google Cloud Console Project (in your case this is "MyApp2018"). The YouTube Data API does not differentiate between channels, so regardless which of your end users wants to upload a video through your app, the API operation will always be added to your application's quota.

Comment: so do I need to check anything before uploading the video for my users? and where do I get any information in my API response that your App quota is full (maybe in future if quota gets full)?

Comment: You don't have to do check anything. Actually, I don't think there is an official way to get an application's remaining quota. If you don't have enough quota left, the API will respond with a `403` status code, details of which you can find [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors#gdata.CoreErrorDomain).

Comment: If you're new to the YouTube Data API v3, I recommend reading the [Getting started guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started). It contains a section about quota as well.

Comment: ok got it, one more question, suppose my app in the market then how I will ensure that I have enough quota available, maybe someday our users will start seeing this error when uploading the videos. So, is there any way to notify me when less quota is available so that I can request to Google to increase it.

Comment: You can check your Quota page for YouTube API to track the volume of request your app is making **per day**, **per 100 sec** and **per 100 sec per user** which can be your when you enable your API in the developer console. I suggest that you first do a stress testing for your app to see if the given quota limit is sufficient enough for your target users.

Comment: Yes, @Mr.Rebot is absolutely right. You can check your quota in the Google Cloud Console (-> API's & Services -> YouTube Data API v3 -> Quotas). What I meant to say in my earlier comment is that there is no way known to me to check your remaining quota *programatically*, i.e. there is no API for the Cloud Console (afaik).